# Получить динамические данные с сайта [Python]

Tags: python, request, requests

При заполнении поля поиска, отправляется запрос на 
 `https://example.com/request/` и в соответствии с ним выводятся подходящие темы.

В Консоли разработчика Chrome показываются следующие данные:

```
General: request post
```

`Request headers:` куча данных, просто перенес их в переменную headers (также ней содержатся куки, эти данные я не переносил, если покажете как их получать, буду благодарен).

```
Request payload: {"Search":{"Topics":["all"],"Start":"Author","Messages":[1],"Types":["answered","unanswered"],"AuthorID":0,"ShowAllInOnePage":true}}
```

Я делаю так:

```
import requests
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

`Payload` в `Python` выглядит так:

```
{"Search":{"Topics":["all"],"Start":"Author","Messages":[1],"Types":
["answered","unanswered"],"AuthorID":0,"ShowAllInOnePage":True}}
```

Я не уверен, что это правильный вариант, где-то написано, что массивы нужно объявлять как `"array[]" : ["key1", "key2"]`.

Еще я не уверен, нужно ли числа переводить в строки или нет
`"Integer" : 0` или `"Integer" : "0"`.
Опять же буду благодарен за пример `payload`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Куки можно посмотреть в консоли разработчика в запросе к сайту в заголовке `Cookie`.

Передача словаря зависит от того, в каком виде данные передаются -- смотреть нужно в запросе на заголовок `Content-Type`.

Например, данные с формы (`<form>`) при отправке имеют тип `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` и в `requests.post` они указываются в параметре `data`: `requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data=data).json()`

Если на сайте есть ajax, то он скорее всего отправляет `json`, тогда у него тип будет `application/json`: `requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', json=data).json()`

---

> Я не уверен, что это правильный вариант, где-то написано, что массивы
> нужно объявлять как "array[]" : ["key1", "key2"].

Так объявляются ассоциативные массивы их еще словарями называют и они имеют ввид `<ключ>: <значение>`. В словаре `{"array[]": ["key1", "key2"]}`, ключ это `"array[]"`, а значение ключа список `["key1", "key2"]`. А если вы имели ввиду что для массивов нужно `[]` добавлять, то это неправда.

> Еще я не уверен, нужно ли числа переводить в строки или нет "Integer"
> : 0 или "Integer" : "0".

Лучше оставлять как есть, т.к. неизвестно как сервер обрабатывает данные и не возникнет ли там проблема (например он ожидает целое число, а отправили строку, да и банально сервер может у себя внутри ругнуться на это несоответствие, а клиенту вернуть пустые данные, а вы будете думать что все хорошо, раз данные пришли и ошибок не выдали)

---

Приведу пример отправки данных через `POST`:

```
import requests

data = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

# Отправка данных в формате формы:
rs = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data=data)
print(rs.json())

# Результат из httpbin.org позволит узнать какие заголовки были сгенерированы и какие данные отправили:
{'args': {}, 'data': '', 'files': {}, 'form': {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}, 'headers': {'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Connection': 'close', 'Content-Length': '7', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Host': 'httpbin.org', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.18.4'}, 'json': None, 'origin': '31.47.110.37', 'url': 'http://httpbin.org/post'}

# Отправка данных в json:
rs = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', json=data)
print(rs.json())
```

Результат:

```json
{'args': {}, 'data': '{"a": 1, "b": 2}', 'files': {}, 'form': {}, 'headers': {'Accept': '*/*', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Connection': 'close', 'Content-Length': '16', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Host': 'httpbin.org', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.18.4'}, 'json': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 'origin': '31.47.110.37', 'url': 'http://httpbin.org/post'}
```